# get the key name from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, postman

Here is my sample JSON ResponseData of form0:

```
{
    "MaterialType": "camera",
    "AssetID": 202773,
    "forms": [
        {
            "release": "asyncCmd/accessCameraMulti",
            "action": "rest/Asset/202773/cameraAccessMultiple",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "cameras",
                    "fieldType": "json",
                    "jsonSchema": "rest/schemas/camera",
                    "instanceIds": {
                        "12202773.2.0": [
                            "MJPEG:MPEG4",
                            "FLV:H264",
                            "RTSP:H264"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
```

I want to retrieve the key name of `instanceIds` i.e  `"12202773.2.0"` and store it in a variable.

`jsonData.forms[0].fields[0].instanceIds` is giving me the values and not the key name.

Comment: `Object.keys(jsonData.forms[0].fields[0].instanceIds)` perhaps?

Comment: thanks. i wasnt knowing that it is that simple. was trying to loop thro all JSON elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Object.keys(jsonData.forms[0].fields[0].instanceIds)
```

This should return an array of the keys for instanceIds, to get the first one you can then reference it with [0].

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Object.keys(jsonData.forms[0].fields[0].instanceIds)`.

It will give you the array of name 122.

Answer (score 0):

Postman has [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) built-in so you could also use the [_.keys()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys) function, which would basically be doing the same thing as `Object.keys`.

```
_.keys(jsonData.forms[0].fields[0].instanceIds)
```